# How to query select one column to different column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select a value from one column but a different column Name

my query

```
select t1.id, name, color, value tone, value image
from tbl_a t1, tbl_b t2
where t1.id = t2.id
```

**Table A**

```
---------------
  id  |  name
---------------
  1   |  A
  2   |  B
---------------
```

**Table B**

```
-------------------------------------
  id  |  color |  type  |  value
<b>--------------------------------------
  1   |  red   |  2     |  red.jpg
  1   |  red   |  1     |  hot
  2   |  blue  |  2     |  blue.jpg
  2   |  blue  |  1     |  cool
-------------------------------------
```

I want to result in this

**Result**

```
------------------------------------
  id  |  color |  tone  |  image
<b>------------------------------------
  1   |  red   |  hot   | red.jpg
  2   |  blue  |  cool  | blue.jpg 
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not need `tbl_a` at all. You only need to query like this:

```
select id,color,
       max(case when type=1 then value end) as tone,
       max(case when type=2 then value end) as image 
from tbl_b
group by id, color;
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a84749f8c8a4e8b147b2b4f3965494de)